# Diretiva como parametro de function?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, funções, diretivas-de-compilação

é possivel setar diretivas como parametros de uma function ja na pagina html?
eu tentei fazar `serviceLogin({{login.user}},{{login.pass}})`mas acredito que não seja o correto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apenas uma correção `{{login.user}}` não é uma diretiva, é uma expressão.

Agora respondendo, você não precisa utilizar a expressão, basta inserir `serviceLogin(login.user, login.pass)` que o angular entenderá que você está se referindo as variáveis presentes no objeto login.